# Seemingly crying cat sound, yet she continues friendly rubbing on me

Tags: cats, behavior, psychology, vocalizations, communication

I live with someone else and their cat will cry at me sometimes and request a "pet" or "rub down".

I read up a little bit about certain cat behaviors and found I may have just been baited in to getting the cat's pheromone on me but the crying sound is a strange precursor to the rubbing against me.

What is the significance of these particular feline behaviors?

Additionally: this cat is a female and estimated 10 years old or older, and lives not only with me and its owner, but also two dogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feline vocalizations can cover a wide range, and this sound is almost certainly not "crying".

Scent marking or not, voluntarily coming over and rubbing against you is a friendly greeting.

Comment: Thank you. The "crying" sound is definitely subjective. I'm not at all able to hear the distinctions between the varieties of vocalizations so I'll just try to recognize this one as a sound that doesn't signify the cat is annoyed :)

Answer (score 1):

The cat is not crying, it is most likely a friendly meow. The cat likes you and wants you to pet her. When she rubs against you, it's means she considers you family.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I like both current answers and kinda wish I could have both as the answer.